# How to display achieved vs targeted in doughnut2d fusion chart

Tags: javascript, fusioncharts

http://www.fusioncharts.com/dev/chart-attributes.html?chart=doughnut2d

http://jsfiddle.net/9cPeU/542/

In doughnut2d I need to display achieved vs. targeted

lets say sales guy got assigned to 50 leads and he had completed 47

what is the data need to send to get this as graph

```
"data": [{
                                    label: 'achieved',
                                    value: 47
                                }, {
                                    label: 'targeted',
                                    value: 50
                                }],

    But currently in graph is  displaying 52% and 48%
```

this jsfiddle gives the information regarding data to be displayed :http://jsfiddle.net/nbHLm/353/:

this image depicts the current graph
[image]

Answer (score -1):

Try setting the attribute "showPercentValues": "0" at chart level.

Comment: that will only removes the % .

Comment: the values will be exactly the same as per your JSON data.

Comment: as per my question , we need to plot achieved vs targeted , displaying data is not as important as plotting , when we plot this 47 , and 50 , doughnut2d will aggregate to 100% , but my question is 50 it self a 100% and 47 is completion in 100%